# Full calendar wont display time label

Tags: jquery, mysql, fullcalendar

I changed my full calendar to display times 8.30am - 10.30pm with 1hour intervals and the label for the times from the calendar.

Here are the display settings for the calendar:

```
allDaySlot: false,
minTime: "08:30",
maxTime: "22:30",
slotDuration: "01:00:00",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this a known bug with minTime. 
The bug is still open here: https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/2786

User adrianolsk provided a workaround that helps https://jsfiddle.net/7ttnwvw5/2/

"

```
function TimeFix(durationInMinutes, minTime) {
        var hour = moment(minTime, "HH:mm");
        $(".fc-body .fc-slats table tr").each(function (index) {
            $(this).find("td.fc-widget-content").eq(0).html("<span>" + hour.format("HH:mm") + "</span>")
            hour.add(durationInMinutes, "minutes");
        });
```

}

and I call it on viewRender event

```
viewRender: function (view, element) {
    TimeFix(30, "08:15:00");                   
}
```

"

Comment: Thanks for this fix!